# Cordova: Cannot find modulde body-parser

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have run this command on my root console

```
npm install --save
```

At the root of my folder
This is a snippet from my ionic-gcm.js

```
var app = express();


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());


var server = app.listen(3000, function(){

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
```

When I run this command, node ionic-gcm.js
I keep getting this error 
Error: Cannot find module body-parser

===============================package.json======================

```
{
  "name": "ionic-gcm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ionic-gcm: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.3",
    "node-gcm": "^0.11.0",
    "server": "0.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "org.apache.cordova.device",
    "org.apache.cordova.console",
    "com.ionic.keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android"
  ]
}
```

Comment: how does your `package.json` look like? maybe you did't include body-parser?

Comment: please take a look of my package.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing `body-parser`. just type

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Comment: You are my hero for today!